# jsp: include file not found exception

Tags: java, jsp, filepath

My file structure in eclipse is

```
src/
   com.test/
            Servlet1.java
```

I am trying to refer to it in JSP using

```
<jsp:include page="com.test/Servlet1"></jsp:include>
```

It gives me the `File not found` error.

Here com.test is the package name and `Servlet1.java` is the servlet file I want to use.

Comment: Has your URL mapping of `Servlet1` configured in your `web.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `<jsp:include>` is

```
<jsp:include page="{relativeURL | <%= expression%>}" flush="true" />
```

So `page` attribute should be a relative URL rather than a Servlet file path.

For example, if you configure your `Servlet1` as:

```
<servlet>   
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>   
    <servlet-class>com.test.Servlet1</servlet-class>   
</servlet>   
<servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>   
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then your `jsp:include` tag should be:

```
<jsp:include page="/test"></jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe com.test makes a new folder named "test" inside a folder named "com" which means the path should be com/test/Servlet1 instead of your com.test, not completely sure tho